# Serialize HashTable to string and back

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to serialize a Hashtable into a string and then back into a hash table but my code for deserializing keeps failing.

To Deserialize:

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(hash.value);
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
ms.Write (bytes,0,bytes.Length);
ms.Seek(0,System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
Hashtable h = (Hashtable)bf.Deserialize(ms);
```

To Serialize:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(ms, hash);
byte[] bt = ms.ToArray();
this.value=System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bt);
```

This is the error I am getting with the above code:
`EndOfStreamException: Failed to read past end of stream.`

But if anyone has a more efficient way to do this I am all ears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Unicode encoding is the problem. Serialized bytes consist of random bytes, including illegel bytes for the unicode encoding. Use **System.Convert.ToBase64String** and **System.Convert.FromBase64String** instead of **Encoding.Unicode.GetString** and **Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes**.
2. But why are you using a string as a medium? An array of bytes is enough to save and load data.

Comment: I have tried Converting to/from base64 string and I get the following error on FromBase64String`FormatException: Invalid length.`

I have to use string as a medium due to the constraints of the framework I am working on (this is part of a plugin).

Comment: For some reason the Serializing part of the code always returns a string with a length of 3 0.o

Comment: What? That's strange. If you use ToBase64String right way, a length of the result string should be multiples of 4.

Comment: I agree, after several hours of looking at the same code over and over, I found out it was an error with the framework not returning the correct value.  :p  Thanks for the help! :)